# Align rightmost column only using Vim and the Tabular plugin

Tags: vim, text-editor, editing, vim-plugin, tabular

I'm using Vim and the popular Tabular plugin.

I want to right-align the rightmost column of numbers *only*. I want to keep the other three columns exactly as they are:  column 1 must remain right-aligned, and columns 2 and 3 must remain left-aligned. How do I do this?

```
 1  foo   bary  42
 2  foox  bar   689
 3  foo   bary  1
 4  foox  bar   3091
 5  foo   bary  2105
 6  foox  bar   7
 7  foo   bary  6
 8  foox  bar   300
 9  foo   bary  926
10  foox  bar   69
11  foo   bary  2
12  foox  bar   21
```

Here's the desired result.

```
 1  foo   bary    42
 2  foox  bar    689
 3  foo   bary     1
 4  foox  bar   3091
 5  foo   bary  2105
 6  foox  bar      7
 7  foo   bary     6
 8  foox  bar    300
 9  foo   bary   926
10  foox  bar     69
11  foo   bary     2
12  foox  bar     21
```

Assume for the purpose of this general class of problem that the strings that separate columns are one or more spaces.

Thank you for your help.

Jim Monty

Comment: Your second column also is updated in the desired result. I doubt if `Tabularize` can do that ;)

Comment: Good eye! I fixed those inadvertent errors in my example result. Thanks, Amit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
:Tabularize /[0-9]*$/l2r0
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: That's the secret sauce. _Thanks, Amit!_ Variations of essentially the same regular expression work, too. For example: `:Tabularize /\d\+$/l2r0`, `:Tabularize /\v\d+/l2r0`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by three regex also:

```
:%s/$/           /g
:%s/\%>20c.*//
:%s/\(\%>10c\s\+\)\(\w\+\)\(\s\+$\)/\1\3\2
```